# How do I get the body from this example HTTP request?

Tags: java, http, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to find the simplest way to parse an RFC-822 document in Java. Assume that I have a message-queue on which HTTP messages are stored. Both requests and responses. So they are not retrieved in the "normal" way by making a socket-connection to - say - port 80 and sending/retrieving the message from there.

In the code below, I deliberately mixed "mail" headers with a HTTP message. It's meant as a demonstration that the two are not very different. But that's beside the point. Here's the code:

```
package httpexample;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestParser;
import org.apache.http.impl.io.HttpTransportMetricsImpl;
import org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl;
import org.apache.http.io.HttpMessageParser;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;

public class HttpExample {

    // RFC 822

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, HttpException {
        String str = "POST http://localhost:8080/foobar/1234567 HTTP/1.1\n" +
            "Message-ID: <19815303.1075861029555.JavaMail.ss@kk>\n" +
            "Date: Wed, 6 Mar 2010 12:32:20 -0800 (PST)\n" +
            "From: someone@someotherplace.com\n" +
            "To: someone@someplace.com\n" +
            "Subject: some subject\n" +
            "Mime-Version: 1.0\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
            "X-From: one, some <some.one@someotherplace.com>\n" +
            "X-To: one\n" +
            "X-cc: \n" +
            "X-bcc: \n" +
            "X-Origin: Bob-R\n" +
            "X-FileName: rbob (Non-Privileged).pst\n" +
            "\n" +
            "some message\n";
        ByteArrayInputStream fakeStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                str.getBytes());
        HttpTransportMetricsImpl metrics = new HttpTransportMetricsImpl();
        SessionInputBufferImpl inbuffer = new SessionInputBufferImpl(metrics, 1024);

        inbuffer.bind(fakeStream);
        HttpMessageParser<HttpRequest> requestParser =
                new DefaultHttpRequestParser(inbuffer);
        BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = (BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest)requestParser.parse();

        for (Header hdr : request.getAllHeaders()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-30s = %s", hdr.getName(), hdr.getValue()));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Request Line: %s", request.getRequestLine()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Body\n------------------\n%s",
                request.getEntity()));
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Message-ID                     = <19815303.1075861029555.JavaMail.ss@kk>
Date                           = Wed, 6 Mar 2010 12:32:20 -0800 (PST)
From                           = someone@someotherplace.com
To                             = someone@someplace.com
Subject                        = some subject
Mime-Version                   = 1.0
Content-Type                   = text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding      = 7bit
X-From                         = one, some <some.one@someotherplace.com>
X-To                           = one
X-cc                           = 
X-bcc                          = 
X-Origin                       = Bob-R
X-FileName                     = rbob (Non-Privileged).pst
Request Line: POST http://localhost:8080/foobar/1234567 HTTP/1.1
Body
------------------
null
```

What I can't figure out, is how to access the *body* of the message.

I would expect it to have the content `some message\n`

I can't find any method in `BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest` that would give me this value. In an earlier version I used

```
HttpRequest request = requestParser.parse();
```

instead of

```
BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = 
    (BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest) requestParser.parse();
```

I changed it to `BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest` because that has the `getEntity` method. But that returns `null`.

So I'm a bit lost.

Where do I find the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added **Content-Length** header, otherwise the parser simply ignores the POST body. I have modified your code, now it parses the body just fine:

```
package org.apache.http.examples;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HttpExample {

    // RFC 822

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, HttpException {
        String str = "POST http://localhost:8080/foobar/1234567 HTTP/1.1\n" +
            "Message-ID: <19815303.1075861029555.JavaMail.ss@kk>\n" +
            "Date: Wed, 6 Mar 2010 12:32:20 -0800 (PST)\n" +
            "From: someone@someotherplace.com\n" +
            "To: someone@someplace.com\n" +
            "Subject: some subject\n" +
            "Mime-Version: 1.0\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
            "X-From: one, some <some.one@someotherplace.com>\n" +
            "X-To: one\n" +
            "X-cc: \n" +
            "X-bcc: \n" +
            "X-Origin: Bob-R\n" +
            "X-FileName: rbob (Non-Privileged).pst\n" +
            "Content-Length: 13\n" +
            "\n" +
            "some message\n";
        ByteArrayInputStream fakeStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                str.getBytes());

        BHttpConnectionBaseImpl b = new BHttpConnectionBaseImpl(fakeStream);

        BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest request1 = (BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest) b.receiveRequestHeader();
        b.receiveRequestEntity(request1);


        for (Header hdr : request1.getAllHeaders()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%-30s = %s", hdr.getName(), hdr.getValue()));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Request Line: %s", request1.getRequestLine()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Body\n------------------\n%s",
                EntityUtils.toString( request1.getEntity() ) ));
    }

}

class BHttpConnectionBaseImpl extends  org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection{

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public BHttpConnectionBaseImpl(final InputStream inputStream) {
        super(4048);
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        try {
            super.bind(new Socket());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getSocketInputStream(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    protected OutputStream getSocketOutputStream(final Socket socket) throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }
}
```

The parsing of POST body happens in `org.apache.http.impl.BHttpConnectionBase.prepareInput(HttpMessage)`, whoever its only constructor is **protected** and requires a lot of parameters. The child `org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpServerConnection` has a convenient public constructor and does the header parsing in `receiveRequestHeader()`. The methods I'm overloading are need to bypass some error checks, e.g. if the `Socket == null` and to be able to read the request from the `fakeStream`

Another approach that might working, although I have not tested it, is to override `Socket` particularly its `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()`. Then create an instance of `DefaultBHttpServerConnection` and call its `bind` method. The rest should be the same.

Comment: I consider this the correct answer as it is reduced to the essential: `Content-Length` and `DefaultBHttpServerConnection`. Neither `Transfer-Encoding` nor `.getBytes()` are at fault. You may want to add a little note about `DefaultBHttpServerConnection` and why it's needed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that it's not clear from your message headers what's the length of the body, so the receiver just ignores it. [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) defines several options on how to convey this information and none of them seems to be applied here:

1. `Content-Transfer-Encoding` must be `Transfer-Encoding`
2. `7bit` is not among [the standard options](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.6).
3. When you use `str.getBytes()`, it gives you UTF-16 bytes which is not `us-ascii` declared in `Content-Type`.

So, I would change your request a bit:

1. Use header `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-16`
2. Remove header `Content-Transfer-Encoding`
3. Add `Content-Lenght: 28` (28 being `"some message\n".getBytes().length()`).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of DefaultHttpRequestParser it seems it only parses the request line and the headers, it does not attempt to parse the body.

[This thread is discussing the same topic. There are few solution proposals as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259232/httprequest-returning-null-entity-cannot-extract-body-on-server)

Answer (score 0):

custom parse head through overwirte the LineParser:

```
inbuffer = new SessionInputBufferImpl(new HttpTransportMetricsImpl(), reqDataLength);
inbuffer.bind(input);
HttpMessageParser<org.apache.http.HttpRequest> requestParser = new DefaultHttpRequestParser(
                inbuffer,
                new LineParser(),
                new DefaultHttpRequestFactory(),
                MessageConstraints.DEFAULT
        );
```

get the entity body as follows:

```
        HttpEntityEnclosingRequest ereq = (HttpEntityEnclosingRequest) req;
        ContentLengthStrategy contentLengthStrategy =
                    StrictContentLengthStrategy.INSTANCE;
        long len = contentLengthStrategy.determineLength(req);
        InputStream contentStream = null;
        if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.CHUNKED) {
            contentStream = new ChunkedInputStream(buf);
        } else if (len == ContentLengthStrategy.IDENTITY) {
            contentStream = new IdentityInputStream(buf);
        } else {
            contentStream = new ContentLengthInputStream(buf, len);
        }
        BasicHttpEntity ent = new BasicHttpEntity();
        ent.setContent(contentStream);
        ereq.setEntity(ent);
        return ereq;
```

Comment: Usually is a good idea to comment why this answers the question.

Comment: The above method allows us to easily customize the parsing of the http header method, which allows us to obtain body data via HttpEntityEnclosingRequest.